# css toggleClass not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

Good day to all,

I want to toggle classes as soon as I click to one of the images. Once I click I want to add a class to that `div` with a name `expand` to give it a little transition effect. So here's my problem. First click, OK. Second click, the class `expand` won't go off. Here are some of my files.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

index.html

```
<div class="box1">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="img/some.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

some.js

```
$(function () {
  $("img").on("click", function() {
    var box = $(this).first().parents().eq(1).attr("class");
    $("."+box).toggleClass("expand");
  });
});
```

some.css

```
.box1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
}

div {
  -webkit-transition-property: width, height;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
}

div.expand {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not work on successive clicks because you are taking the entire `class` attribute and then looking for the element named `$('.box1 expand')`, which does not exist. Instead, use `toggleClass` on the element itself, instead of building the class selector:

```
$("img").on("click", function() {
    $(this).first().parents().eq(1).toggleClass("expand");
});
```

Or alternatively, you can clean the code slightly by using `closest()`:

```
$("img").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('box1').toggleClass("expand");
});
```

Comment: That was fast. Thank you very much! Been banging my head for hours because of this. Thanks again